# More efficient Omnibus number determination?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, pattern-matching, integer-sequence

Amusing myself with concepts from ["Omnibus Sequences, Coupon Collection, and Missing Word Counts"](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0905.4517.pdf?origin=publication_detail), in particular the sequences.

To paraphrase the concept, a string is *k-Omni* over some alphabet *a* if any string of length *k* (or less) from the alphabet can be found as a sequence of the string.

e.g.,

```
string={5, 4, 0, 5, 3, 3, 1, 4, 0, 2, 4, 0, 2, 3, 5, 0, 0, 0, 5, 4, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 4, 1, 5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 4}
```

is 2-Omni over the alphabet of the string, and 4-Omni over a restricted alphabet of `{1,2,3}`.

I'm using

```
kOmni = Block[{f = Total@BitSet[0, DeleteDuplicates@#1], z, cnt = 0},
   Fold[If[(z = BitAnd[f, BitSet[#, #2]]) == f, cnt++; 0, z] &, 0, #2];cnt] &
```

which takes the alphabet and string as arguments, to determine the *k* for various conditions, e.g. `kOmni[{1, 2, 3}, string]` returns the desired 4 result.

Might there be a more efficient way to do this? You can assume strings (and alphabets) are limited to non-negative integers, and alphabets are almost always under 200 distinct values, but the strings can be quite large (>10^5 elements).

Update: An optimization I came up with nodding off...

```
kOmniO = Block[{f, z, cnt = 0, s = #2, a = DeleteDuplicates@#1},
   s = Join[a, s];
   s = s[[Sort@(Join @@ 
         GatherBy[Range@Length@s, s[[#]] &][[;; Length@a, 2 ;;]])]];
   f = Total@BitSet[0, a];
   Fold[If[(z = BitSet[#, #2]) == f, cnt++; 0, z] &, 0, s];
   cnt] &
```

About 50% faster for full alphabet, and with alphabet that is a subset of string alphabet, can be over an order of magnitude faster. I still have a gut feeling there's a faster/smarter way to do this... c'mon wizards ;-)

Comment: Sorry to be dense but I don't understand your example.  What are the 4-Omni strings for alphabet {1, 2, 3}?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard:`Tuples[{1, 2, 3}, {4}]`...

 `And @@ (LongestCommonSequence[#, string] == # & /@ Tuples[{1, 2, 3}, {#}]) & /@ {4, 5}` -> `{True,False}`

So, the *string* in the example has all of those tuples of length 4 as subsequences, and *it* is 4-omni (not the subsequences themselves).

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: To clarify, as a *sequence* of the string in *Mathematica* terminology (vs *subsequence*).

Comment: Got it; I was thinking contiguous sequence and I couldn't see it.  Now your function makes more sense. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Yeah, I realized after the fact I used the *mathematical* terminology in my reply - has always irked me a bit MMA didn't name them "LongestCommonSequence" and "LongestCommonContiguousSequence"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont know how to solve your question,but I know that just compile it will save some times.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
string = {5, 4, 0, 5, 3, 3, 1, 4, 0, 2, 4, 0, 2, 3, 5, 0, 0, 0, 5, 4, 
   2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 4, 1, 5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 4};
kOmni = Block[{f = Total@BitSet[0, DeleteDuplicates@#1], z, cnt = 0}, 
    Fold[If[(z = BitAnd[f, BitSet[#, #2]]) == f, cnt++; 0, z] &, 0, #2]; cnt] &;
kOmni2 = Compile[{{substring, _Integer, 1}, {string, _Integer, 1}},
   Module[{f, z = 0, cnt = 0},
      f = Total@BitSet[0, DeleteDuplicates@substring];
      Fold[If[(z = BitAnd[f, BitSet[#, #2]]) == f, cnt++; 0, z] &, 0, string]; cnt
    ]
   ];
Do[kOmni[{1, 2, 3}, string], {5000}] // Timing
Do[kOmni2[{1, 2, 3}, string], {5000}] // Timing
```

> {0.936006, Null}
>
> {0.234002, Null}

Comment: Of course I compile it for actual use - not posted to keep post cleaner. Nonetheless, since you answered, bounty is yours, and +1